# jssor two independent sliders on a single page

Tags: jssor, sliders

I would like to ask if I can have two independent jssor sliders in a single page. What I want to do is create 2 sliders which will act as a separate part of the page. That means that I want the animations of the 2 sliders start simultaneously.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks!

Comment: include what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slider1_container" ...>
    ...
</div>

<div id="slider2_container" ...>
    ...
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options1 = {...};
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options1);

        var options2 = {...};
        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options2);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want a main slider which will include a second one. But the effects of the main one I want to be independent from the other. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Please just place your second slider in any slide of the main slider.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer.

Can I import caption transitions in the nested-slider.source.html file of the jssor pack? I build my own sliders in this file but when I add the array for the caption transitions nothing happened. What should I do in order to make slides with images and captions animations?

Have a look of my code if you want. I don't know if all of this code is necessary for me..Here is the jquery:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var nestedSliders = [];

        $.each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container"], function (index, containerId) {
            var nestedSliderOptions = {
                $AutoPlay:true,
                $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
                $SlideDuration: 1000,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                }
            };

            nestedSliders.push(new $JssorSlider$(containerId, nestedSliderOptions));
        });

         var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 300,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 80,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0),
            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },              

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $AutoCenter: 3,                                 //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
                $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 3,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                $DisableDrag: false                            //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        function OnMainSliderPark(currentIndex, fromIndex) {
            $.each(nestedSliders, function (index, nestedSlider) {
                nestedSlider.$Pause();
            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                nestedSliders[currentIndex].$Play();
            }, 2000);
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnMainSliderPark);
        OnMainSliderPark(0, 0);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 600));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
```

And the HTML code is here:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1280px; height: 720px; overflow: hidden; ">
```

```
        <div id="slider2">
            <div id="sliderh2_container" class="sliderh2" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 764px;
                height: 720px;">

                <!-- Slides Container -->
                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 764px; height: 720px;
                    overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>
                        <div><img u="image" src="images/logo.png" /></div>
                        <div u="caption" t="CLIP|LR" t2="ZML|R">test</div>
                    </div>
                    <div><img u="image" src="images/address.png" /></div>
                    <div><img u="image" src="images/logo.png" /></div>
                    <div><img u="image" src="images/address.png" /></div>
                </div>                   
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: See 'examples-jquery\slider-with-caption.source.html'. Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html